# How to exclude zero values in wavelet transform

Tags: python, wavelet-transform, pywt

I'm removing noise using a wavelet transform, but the noise removal result looks messy for zero value. So, how do I exclude zero values in a wavelet transform?

My code is here:

```py
import pywt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram

df = pd.read_csv('1225JakariaRwalk2Min.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx','Fy','Fz','Mx','My','Mz']
selected_df = df[columns]
FPDatas = selected_df[:15000]

FPData = np.array(FPDatas).astype('float64')

wavelet = 'db4'

DWTcoeffs = []
for i in range(6):
    coeffs = pywt.wavedec(FPData[:, i], wavelet)
    coeffs[-1] = np.zeros_like(coeffs[-1])
    coeffs[-2] = np.zeros_like(coeffs[-2])
    coeffs[-3] = np.zeros_like(coeffs[-3])
    DWTcoeffs.append(coeffs)

filtered_data_dwt = np.zeros(FPData.shape)
for i in range(6):
    filtered_data_dwt[:, i] = pywt.waverec(DWTcoeffs[i], 'db4', mode='symmetric', axis=0)
    
for i in range(6):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    plt.plot(FPData[:2000, i], color='red')
    plt.plot(filtered_data_dwt[:2000, i], markerfacecolor='none', color='black')
    plt.legend(['Real Data', 'Denoised Data'], loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

Denoising data results:
[image]

Dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yi19FHFxmRpJ7CQ58IoPS4rWq3Nm0YrX/view?usp=sharing

You can download the dataset and run the code to answer this question.

Comment: The csv file stored on your Google Drive is called **0311LalaStand5Min1.csv**, not **1225JakariaRwalk2Min.csv**.

Comment: I've update the link of dataset.